# How to print to file output (in addition to finding) all possible states of a set of 12 lines

Tags: python, combinations

I have 12 lines (including the numbers before |). Each line can contain the natural numbers between 1 and the maximum which is 12 in reference to 12 lines. I would like to find and print all possible states in which these 12 lines may be. Below 3 Examples of states.

```
1  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
2  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
3  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
4  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
5  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
6  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
7  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
8  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
9  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
10 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
11 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
12 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

---

```
1  | 1 2 3 4 
2  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
3  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 
4  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
5  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 
6  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
7  | 1 2 3 4 
8  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
9  | 1 2 3 4 5 
10 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
11 | 1 2 3 4 5 
12 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

---

```
1  | 1 
2  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
3  | 10 11 12
4  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
5  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
6  | 7 8 9 10
7  | 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
8  | 1 2 3 4 5 6 
9  | 3 4 5 6 7
10 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 
11 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
12 | 10 11 12
```

I do not know if this is right place for my question maybe the answer I look for is a python script, thank you if you can guide me about it.

The only combination method (but not enough) I know in Python is the script below

```
import sys
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

file = open('output.txt', 'a')
stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = file
print(list(powerset("1234567989")))

sys.stdout = stdout
file.close()
```

I think I'm going to need to use `for loop`, maybe with 11 ties?

Note: In my understanding the total number of combinations is 12x12 = 8.9161004e+12

Comment: If your understanding of the problem is that there are  8,916,100,400,000 results, do you really need this printed to the terminal?

Comment: @TheQueenIsDead I say print stdout for file (e.g. output.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your understanding might be wrong. If I understood the possible combinations correctly, I don't count `12^12` but `sum(range(1,13))^12` combinations.

Explanation: for each line you have the following possible combinations:

- 12 possibilities if the line starts with 1
- 11 if it starts with 2 and so on
- ...
- 1 if it starts with 12

So this gives you the sum from 1 to 12 (`sum(range(1,13))`). Then combine that with all your 12 lines and you get the power of 12.

You can print them with nested loops but your script will crash at some point: you'd have a file with 50714860157241037295616 combinations * 12 lines (not counting additional line breaks) which would be several thousand Exabytes.

Comment: I was just about to do some math and mention the size of the results themselves.. . beat me to it! I think the Op need to really reconsider what problem they're trying to solve with their dataset